# How to bring an image to front in ScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm showing images in the `ScrollView` but I want to know please how can I bring each image to the front in the middle while I'm scrolling. Also it is on the back on each other as in the picture below.

[image]

My code:

```
-(void)scrollView2{

    _scrlView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _scrlView.pagingEnabled = NO;
    _scrlView.bounces = false;
    _scrlView.delegate = self;
    _scrlView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    _scrlView.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
    _scrlView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrlView.frame.size.width, _scrlView.frame.size.height);

    _scrlView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrlView.frame.size.width * 2, _scrlView.frame.size.height);

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    int segment = screenWidth / 5;

    int screenX2 = screenHeight/2 - segment/2;

    __block float x = (screenWidth-segment)/2;

    NSArray *arrImages=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Smiley-1.png",@"Smiley-2.png",@"Smiley-3.png",@"Smiley-4.png",@"Smiley-5.png", nil];

    for(int i=0;i<arrImages.count;i++)
    {
        UIImageView *imgVw=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
        [imgVw setFrame:CGRectMake(x, screenX2, segment, segment)];
        [imgVw setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrImages objectAtIndex:i]]]];
        [imgVw setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [imgVw setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
        [_scrlView addSubview:imgVw];

        x=x+segment;
    }

    [self.view addSubview:_scrlView];
}

float oldY;

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

  int scrollX = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
  int position = scrollX/segment;

  NSLog(@"X: %f , position: %d", scrollView.contentOffset.x , position);

  [_scrlView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(_scrlView.contentOffset.x, oldY)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bring sub view to front. For instance

`[scrollView bringSubviewToFront:_img1];`

Comment: I know this code but how I can get all back while the one in the middle will be in the front? While it is horizontal uiscrollview

Comment: If you are adding a view or Image it will arrange in the order one by one.. You can't make all to show in front. In this situation you can go with designer to change the three image to one and add it. If a layer means u can use the transform property.. That to end with the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

I understood what you meant, there is an interesting [project](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel). It should help you.

You can also try yourself using a **[UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/)**.

Comment: It looks like it is very complicated project.... How I can make the same thing with `UICollectionView` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   NSArray *arrImages=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"smiley1",@"smiley2",@"smiley3",@"smiley4",@"smiley5",@"smiley6", @"smiley7",@"smiley8", nil];

   screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
   screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
   screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

   UIScrollView *scrlView=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];
   [scrlView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
   scrlView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   scrlView.pagingEnabled = YES;
   scrlView.bounces = false;
   scrlView.delegate = self;
   scrlView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
   scrlView.layer.cornerRadius = 2;

  segmentWidth = screenWidth / 5;

   long ScrollContentSize = ((arrImages.count -1)*segmentWidth)+screenWidth;

   scrlView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(ScrollContentSize, scrlView.frame.size.height);

   float screenX2 = screenHeight/2 - segmentWidth/2;

   __block float screenX = (screenWidth-segmentWidth)/2;

   for(int i=0;i<arrImages.count;i++)
   {
      UIImageView *imgVw=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
      [imgVw setFrame:CGRectMake(screenX, screenX2, segmentWidth+30, segmentWidth+30)];
      [imgVw setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrImages objectAtIndex:i]]]];
      [imgVw setTag:5000+i];
      [imgVw setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
       screenX = screenX+segmentWidth;
      [scrlView addSubview:imgVw];

      if (i%2==0)
      {
         [imgVw setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
         [scrlView sendSubviewToBack:imgVw ];

       }
      else
       {
         [imgVw setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
         [scrlView bringSubviewToFront:imgVw];

       }

   }

   [self.view addSubview:scrlView];


}
```

Try this

Comment: I'm sorry this is not what I want. I want the same look as in the picture above. It should be next to each other.

Comment: Yes, I want the same type. So each image on each other but the one in the middle will be brought to the front

Comment: I have updated my code. once I scroll and one of the image come in the middle I want to bring it to the front and the others stays in the back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75899/discussion-between-can-and-nandu).